# How to find probabilities given the cdf

Tags: probability

I am stuck on this example;

[image]

How do I compute

$P(Y≤X)$

I know it is $P(X^2≤X)$ but I am not sure where to go from there

Comment: Really $X^2\le X$ is equivalent to $0\le X\le 1$ so you just need to calculate $P(0\le X\le 1)=F(1)-F(0)=1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$
\mathbb P(X^2\leqslant X) = \mathbb P(X(X-1)\leqslant 0),
$$
and $$\{X(X-1)\leqslant 0\} = \{X-1\leqslant 0\} = \{X\leqslant 1\},$$
since $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 0)=1$. It follows that
$$
\mathbb P(X^2\leqslant X) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant 1) = \frac12.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to show that $(1)−(0)=1/2$

Hope this helps